# Graphene: ruby bundler install fails

Tags: ruby, linux, graphite

I installed the latest [`graphene`](https://github.com/jondot/graphene) from github in `/opt/graphene` on my Debian 6.0 linux server.  I am trying to code up a [`graphite`](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) dashboard with [`graphene`](https://github.com/jondot/graphene), but I'm having problems with ruby's [`bundler`](http://gembundler.com/)

1. As I follow the [github markdown `README.md`](https://github.com/jondot/graphene/blob/master/README.md), I successfully installed the [`ruby`](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) debian package as well as `rubygems`.
2. Next, I `sudo gem install serve` with no problems.
3. I can surf to the example site on port 4000, so I know that `ruby` and `rubygems` are working...

[image: Successful graphene ruby serve]

Next, I install [`bundler`](http://gembundler.com/) with `sudo gem install bundler` as required by graphene's README; However, when I take the next step in `README.md`, `bundle install` fails...

```
[mpenning@tsunami graphene]$ sudo /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/bin/bundle install
[sudo] password for mpenning: 
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/bin/bundle:2:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/bin/bundle:2
[mpenning@tsunami graphene]$
```

I'm not completely ignorant of `ruby`, but it's confusing why this fails at line 2

```
[mpenning@tsunami graphene]$ sudo head /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/bin/bundle
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'bundler'
# Check if an older version of bundler is installed
$:.each do |path|
  if path =~ %r'/bundler-0.(\d+)' && $1.to_i < 9
    err = "Please remove Bundler 0.8 versions."
    err << "This can be done by running `gem cleanup bundler`."
    abort(err)
  end
end
[mpenning@tsunami graphene]$
```

It's self-evident that `bundler` is installed.  My `ruby`-fu is weak, but it doesn't make sense to me that this fails.  With over 1000 github stars and 76 forks, I doubt the `README.md` is wrong at this step; I suspect it is something in my local environment.

Can someone help me with the correct steps to make `bundle install` work?

Comment: which ruby version are you running? how did you install it?

Comment: It's ruby 1.8.7 installed from the debian package; I have bundler 1.2.0 installed from the gem in `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bundle`.

You can also link it to `/usr/local/bin`, if you want:

```
ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bundle /usr/local/bin/bundle
```

Comment: For some reason this kept failing until I used `sudo /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bundle install --verbose`, but bottom-line it worked after I opened my firewall and used the script you mentioned above.